# How to copy/merge one directory into another like done by default in windows file explorer?

Tags: files-and-directories, windows, .netlink

What is the easiest way to copy one directory into another programmatically?

I tried:

```
CopyDirectory[
    "...location1...\\MyFolder",
    "...location2...\\MyFolder"
]
```

There are two folders with the same name in two different locations (`location1` & `location2`). I can use windows file explorer to copy the `location1`'s `MyFolder` and paste it on the `location2`'s `MyFolder` and it starts merging them, i.e. the following happens:

1. Any subfolder that matches the same path within this folder will also be merged.
2. Any filename that matches gets overwritten.
3. Any file or folder that doesn't exist in `location2`'s `MyFolder` will be copied over from `location1`'s `MyFolder`.
4. Any file or folder which only exists in `location2`'s `MyFolder` will be ignored and will continue to exist in `location2`'s `MyFolder`.

How to do the same operation with `Wolfram`?

Comment: Maybe `CreateArchive`and `ExtractArchive` with the option `OverwriteTarget-> True` ?

Comment: @andre314 Thank you it works!

Comment: Note : I have not studied how the file metainformations (file date, directory date, attributes ...) follow. It can be system dependent (and it's catastrophics with windows file explorer : directory dates don't follow). Idem for maximum file names length .Hope you don't care.

Answer (score 2):

`CreateArchive`and `ExtractArchive` with the option `OverwriteTarget-> True` are probably the solution.

So far I know,`ExtractArchive` is the only way to create a bunch of files in the system without specifying the  name of each file.

Since recently, I use `CreateArchive`and `ExtractArchive` to copy html pages (with the subdirectory of all the linked images) inside the file system.

This is allready usefull, but my true use-case will be for embedding html files in notebooks. For this, I use `Import[ the archived hmtl file, "Byte"]` in a variable called `theEmbeddedData` , and the reverse feature `BinaryWrite[ new copy of the html file , theEmbeddedData]`. Embedding the data of   `theEmbeddeData` in the notebook can be done with `Iconize`, or with a button that extracts the data of `theEmbeddedData` in a tempory directory and open the page.

That will be probably to very very usefull.

I mention this because it's hard to find the 4 main ingredients of the processus : `CreateArchive`, `ExtractArchive`, `Import[...,"Byte"]` and  `BinaryWrite[...]`.

Comment: Using Archiving to merge folders or do other folder operations seems unnatural but at least it works! I will wait to accept this as an answer so that anyone who may know a better way can have an opportunity too.